# Android: usb hid driver in C

Tags: android, c, usb

I need to write a usb "driver" in Android that talks to our custom HID device. I have been able to open and get data from the device using android.hardware.usb from Java, but its much better for us to use a C .so file as all the other code is in C.

My problem is getting permissions for talking to the device without rooting. Is there any way to do this, or is the only way to use USB Host accessory solution as I've experimented with? If needed I we can modify the OS, but another solution would be better.

Comment: Please have a look around at the many existing questions on this subject and see if there are things that, while short of a definitive solution, lead you towards an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I would not have asked if I had not looked without finding a solution to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it is possible to change device permissions by modifying /ueventd.rc. This obviosuly requires you to build your own version of the OS (or be rooted which makes it pointless to change permissions in the first place).